# JPA insert into x as select * from y (HQL)

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, pojo

My knowledge of JPA is less than a week, please bear with me, if this is a silly question.

I have two tables X and Y with identical schema,

I use a findById method of XHome class, if the result passes some checks, I add it int List xList.
Now if X table has 100 rows, xList ends up having close to 10 records.

Now I want to store the elements of this xList to Y table.
So I want to iterate through the list and insert the element into the Y table, using the persist method of YHome class.

Now X and Y are different DTO( bean) of different tables.
so it doesnt allow me to insert X object , as it expects Y.

And Certainly I cant use casting for this as there is no parent child relation .
Is there way in HQL where this is possible.
Unless for each record I have to use the getters of X and set them into using setters of Y before calling persist().

Is there any ready-made solution available?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try this as a start:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Entity1 {
    @Id private int id;


@Entity
public class Entity2 extends Entity1 {
```

And to use it:

```
tx.begin();
Entity1 entity1 = new Entity1();
entity1.setId(1);
em.persist(entity1);
entity1 = new Entity1();
entity1.setId(2);
em.persist(entity1);
tx.commit();
em.clear();

tx.begin();
Query q = em.createQuery("insert into Entity2(id) select e.id from Entity1 e");
int res = q.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("Count = " + res);
tx.commit();
em.close();
```